# Memory leak with singleton

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a singleton class and the lines in the init method cause memory leak, and I don't kwno why...

this is my implementation

```
static timerController *sngTimer = nil;

@implementation timerController

@synthesize repeatingTimer;
@synthesize dateComp;
@synthesize bPause;

+(timerController *) singletonTimer
{
    @synchronized(self){
        if (sngTimer == nil ) 
        {
            sngTimer = [[timerController alloc]init];
        }
    }

    return sngTimer;
}

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil) {

        dateComp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];         ///this line cause memory leak
        NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]; ///this line cause memory leak

        [dateComp setCalendar:gregorianCalendar]; ///this line cause memory leak

        [gregorianCalendar release];

        bPause = FALSE;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Can you mark a singleton as autorelease in Objective-C?  Could you release it in something akin to a C `atexit()` handler?

Comment: is the dateComp property declared as 'retain' or 'copy'? If so, you're leaking the NSDateComponents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you're detecting the leak, but most likely whatever tool you're using notices that you don't have a dealloc method to release the object you create there. You probably should have it for completeness, but as long as the class is only used as a singleton, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a leak. A singleton stays around forever (usually), so it's *supposed* to remain in memory.

Answer (score 1):

[Chuck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158515/memory-leak-with-singleton/4158654#4158654) is correct. Implement a `-dealloc` method, and inside it, set the `dateComp` property to nil or release the corresponding ivar. `-dealloc` will never get called, but it will shut up the static analyzer.

Here's a good article on some of the [subtleties of singletons](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-10-02-care-and-feeding-of-singletons.html).